# Is it tolerable if my system call raises error?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I'm implementing multi stage pipe processes. To avoid race condition, I have to set the process group for the child process in both parent process and child process. However, `setpgid` in the parent process can raise error if the child process has entered `execvp`.

- Is there any rule of thumb that we should quit the program if any system calls raise error?
- Can I catch such error and continue my program?
- Is this a good coding convention?
- Any more elegant ways to handle this case?

---

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      perror(msg);                                  \
      _exit(1);                                     \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

int main () {
  int ls_pid;
  char *ls_argv[] = { "ls", NULL };

  CHECK(ls_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!ls_pid) {
    CHECK(setpgid(0, 0), "setpgid error");
    CHECK(tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, 0), "tcsetpgrp error");
    CHECK(execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv), "execvp error");
  } else {
    // sleep(2);
    setpgid(ls_pid, ls_pid); // This might give error if the child process has entered execvp. 
    // It returns -1 if uncommenting the sleep(2) above.
  }

  CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");
  printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling setpgid in both the parent and the child, for the child?  The two calls do the same thing.  Normally you just call it in the child.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I have to do this when I have multiple child processes. This [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html#Launching-Jobs) says "If both the child processes and the shell call setpgid, this ensures that the right things happen no matter which process gets to it first."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the link below can answer really good to your questions:

[POSIX, Part 1: Error handling](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/POSIX,-Part-1:-Error-handling)

But I don't think you are using a good coding convention. It is low tolerant to faults.